# Getting all layer names from opened .qgz project file using PyQGIS

Tags: pyqgis, layer-name, qgz

I have several *.qgz* project in different directories. I would like to get all the (displayed) layer names from each project. I tried several forms of code to get it from documentation, but it only returns an empty list in each file.

```py
for settlement in os.listdir(source):
    settlement_path = os.path.join(source, str(settlement))
    settlement_name = str(settlement)

    for qgz in os.listdir(settlement_path):
        if str(qgz).endswith('.qgz'):
            project = QgsProject.instance()
            project.read(str(qgz))
            layers_names = []

            for layer in project.mapLayers().values():
                layers_names.append(layer.name())
            print(layers_names)

        project.clear()
```

Comment: Have you made sure your path (`qgz`) is correct?

Comment: I printed out the files and also made a join for paths but the results are same.

Comment: did you try printing out `project.mapLayers()`?

Comment: Returns empty dictionaries in each case. My qgzs for sure aren't empty.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You miss `os.path.join` in the second loop.

Change

```
project.read(str(qgz))
```

to

```
project.read(os.path.join(settlement_path, str(qgz)))
```

Comment: Wow It works! Funny, I tried joining in the second loop as a separate variable and it did not work but in this way it works perfectly. Thank you!